# Creating dummy variables using condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a student and beginner in SQL

I have a table that has columns: `ID_USER, DATE` and `PAYMENT_DUMMY`, which contains information about user payments in each month (*1 - paid, 0 - did not pay*).

I need to create another dummy variable that will identify users who did not pay in the first or first and second months, but paid in the remaining (*in the screenshot, these are users are 1225964 and 1249528*).

Can anyone help me on this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q7wu.jpg]

Comment: 'did not pay in the first or first and second months' - you don't care if paid in first and third, or second and third, or didn't pay at all?

Comment: Yes, It's dot't care

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this where the inner query allocates a row number and the outer query works out how many of the first 2 month have not been paid

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int, dt date, dummy int);
insert into t values 
(1,'2018-01-31',1),(1,'2018-02-28',1),(1,'2018-03-31',1),
(2,'2018-01-31',0),(2,'2018-02-28',0),(2,'2018-03-31',1),
(3,'2018-01-31',1),(3,'2018-02-28',0),(3,'2018-03-31',1),
(4,'2018-01-31',0),(4,'2018-02-28',0),(4,'2018-03-31',0);

    select s.id,sum(dummy) cnt
from
(
select t.*,
        if (t.id <> @p,@r:=1,@r:=@r+1) r,
        @p:=t.id p
from t
cross join (select @r:=0,@p:=0) rn
order by t.id,t.dt
) s
where s.r <= 2 
group by s.id having cnt = 0;

+------+------+
| id   | cnt  |
+------+------+
|    2 |    0 |
|    4 |    0 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```